# How to create the two structural directive in angular 6?

Tags: angular

This question already has an answer but not related to it.  Following code is my code

```
<tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of header" *ngIf='col.name!="Parent"'>
       {{col.value}}
    </th>
</tr>
```

I am creating the header using `ngFor`, I want to skip if the col.name has the particular value

We can skip by using the following , but the empty header is creating

```
    <th *ngFor="let col of header" >
        <span *ngIf='col.name!="Parent"'>
            {{col.value}}
        </span>
    </th>
```

If I'm creating with ng-template header is not showing. How can fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the requirement needs to filter your array before looping. If the condition doesn't match your code will still create a `th` element.
One way to achieve this would be to create a custom pipe which will filter your headers. something like:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterPipe'
})
export class FilterPipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[], filterString: string): any {
    return value.filter(elem => elem.name != filterString);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<th *ngFor="let col of header | filterPipe: 'Parent'" >
    <span>
        {{col.value}}
    </span>
</th>
```

Or the other option could be using `ng-container` for the loop

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of header" >
    <th *ngIf='col.name!="Parent"'>
        <span>
            {{col.value}}
        </span>
    </th>
</ng-container>
```

`ng-container` itself is not rendered in the DOM, its the elements inside ng-container which is rendered, when the `ngIf` condition doesn't satisfy the requirement, your `th` will be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

You can try ng-container. here is documentation of it. [link](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let col of header" >
      <th *ngIf='col.name!="Parent"' >
            <span>
                {{col.value}}
            </span>
        </th>
 </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this, there can only be one structural directive per element:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of header">
    <th *ngIf='col.name!="Parent"' >
        {{col.value}}
    </th>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can use ng-container after tr tag

```
<tr>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let col of header">
      <th  *ngIf='col.name!="Parent"'>
        {{col.value}}
      </th>
   </ng-container>
</tr>
```